# In C++ and C# are multiple condition checks performed in a predetermined or random sequence?

Tags: c#, c++, deterministic, non-deterministic

Situation: condition check in C++ or C# with many criteria:

```
if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3)
{
    // Do something
}
```

I've always believed the sequence in which these checks are performed is not guaranteed. So it is not necessarily first condition1 then condition2 and only then condition3. I learned it in my times with C++. I think I was told that or read it somewhere.

Up until know I've always written secure code to account for possible null pointers in the following situation:

```
if ((object != null) && (object.SomeFunc() != value))
{
    // A bad way of checking (or so I thought)
}
```

So I was writing:

```
if (object != null)
{
    if (object.SomeFunc() != value)
    {
        // A much better and safer way
    }
}
```

Because I was not sure the not-null check will run first and only then the instance method will be called to perform the second check.

Now our greatest community minds are telling me the sequence in which these checks are performed is guaranteed to run in the left-to-right order.

I'm very surprised. Is it really so for both C++ and C# languages?

Has anybody else heard the version I heard before now?

Comment: Subexpressions in C# are evaluated left-to-right, always, period.
Subexpressions in C/C++ are evaluated in sequence-point order.  Two expressions in the same sequence point may be evaluated in any order. Do a web search on "sequence point" if you need a formal definition.

Answer (score 14):

Short Answer is left to right with short-circuit evaluation. The order is predictable.

```
// perfectly legal and quite a standard way to express in C++/C#
if( x != null && x.Count > 0 ) ...
```

Some languages evaluate everything in the condition before branching (VB6 for example).

```
// will fail in VB6 if x is Nothing. 
If x Is Not Nothing And x.Count > 0 Then ...
```

Ref: MSDN [C# Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) and their order or precedence.

Comment: @Robert: Don't you mean "If x is not Nothing && ..." (or equivalent VB6 syntax)?

Comment: @RichieHindle - yes, my recollection of VB6/VBScript is thankfully very old. I'll update

Answer (score 2):

They are defined to be evaluated from left-to-right, **and** to stop evaluating when one of them evaluates to false.  That's true in both C++ and C#.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is or has been any other way.  That would be like the compiler deciding to run statements out of order for no reason. :)  Now, some languages (like VB.NET) have different logical operators for short-circuiting and not short-circuiting.  But, the order is always well defined at compile time.

Here is the [operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(VS.71).aspx) from the C# language spec.  From the spec ...

> Except for the assignment operators,
>   all binary operators are
>   left-associative, meaning that
>   operations are performed from left to
>   right. For example, x + y + z is
>   evaluated as (x + y) + z.

Comment: Again, precedence, associativity and order of subexpression evaluation are three different things. You cannot determine order from precedence in C#.

Comment: Also, I regret that the specification is poorly worded in the bit that you quoted. I've been trying to get that fixed.

Comment: Yes, I see your point.  It's counter-intuitive, but I suppose the operation can be left-associative and still be evaluated out of left to right order.  Both need to be evaluated before the operation can be applied, so precedence does not necessarily imply evaluation order.  But then you would have to give up short circuit as short circuit && would not work (necessarily) with two operators and three operands and || short circuit would not work with two.

Answer (score 0):

They have to be performed from left to right. This allows short circuit evaluation to work.

See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) for more information.